# Scroll View not work properly with padding

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have a problem in my `Activity`. The `ScrollView` doesn't scroll down to the bottom.
Here's my XML layout of the `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/test"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutsPadding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/layoutsPadding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutsPadding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/scrollViewLayoutsPadding">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/tab_introduction_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/layoutsPadding">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_introduction_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bigFont"></TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/gap_titleAndText">
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_introduction_description"
            android:textSize="@dimen/smallFont"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

What Can I do?

Comment: Try removing the `LinearLayout`'s padding.

Comment: worked but I want linear layout to has padding

Comment: Check answer. Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Please wait I am going to check it

Comment: Oh excuse me . my text was too small . when I remove padding it not works properly again

Comment: Make sure you have added padding to the outer `LinearLayout`.

Comment: not worked properly

Comment: Check edit. And please comment on the answer itself. Let me know if that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since removing `LinearLayout`'s padding worked, but you want it to have padding, why not just surround it with another `LinearLayout` and let only this outer `LinearLayout` to have a padding. And remove the inner `LinearLayout`'s padding. This is probably not a very good style, but worth a try.

If you want to avoid this, you can also try removing the padding from the `LinearLayout` and adding a margin to all it's children.

EDIT: Since you really need that padding, adding an empty view at the bottom will definitely solve your problem, but it's not a good solution either:

```
<View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp" />
```

Comment: LinearLayout has three childern . I will try it

Comment: Yeah so add a margin to them, and remove LinearLayout's padding. This problem is happening because your ScrollView and it's direct child LinearLayout, both have a padding.

Comment: Check edit @amirhosseinramazani. This should definitely work. Let me know if it doesn't or if you need more help.